# How to Display each variable of for loop in a div tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to Display each variable of for loop in a div tag using javascript? Using innerHTML i am only able to display the last variable of for loop

Comment: Can you maybe share your code and a include the result you are expecting ?

Comment: What do you mean by "each variable of for loop"?

Comment: _"last variable of for loop"_ sounds like a closure issue. Although without an example I'm just guessing

Comment: You need to make [mre], you can use `<>` in editor to make snippet. This website is all about code, nobody can help you without it. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows, but it is better to use lists.
Lists: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

```js
const myDreams = ["Fly", "Be rich", "Go to the moon"];
const myDreamsDiv = document.querySelector("#myDreams");

//The secret here is to add a breakline(<br>) between each word.
myDreams.forEach(dream => myDreamsDiv.innerHTML += (dream + "<br>"));
```

```html
<div id="myDreams"></div>
```

Comment: In the future, don't link to w3schools. It can be *very* inaccurate. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is usually a better resource. Also, div elements are **not** self closing. The valid HTML would be `<div id="myDreams"></div>`.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 Fixed, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks @alexandre , I was able to display all the variables of for loop , using pretty much the way you used